# How to solve null pointer exception of webdriver in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

This is the code i have written below in junit. However it shows me a null pointer exception for the webdriver.
i have also printed "driver". it prints "drivernull"

```
*package demo;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import java.util.concurrent .TimeUnit;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
class Demo1 {
    public WebDriver driver;
    String url="www.google.com";
    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get(url);
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {


        System.out.println("driver"+driver);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'prm\']/div/a")).click();
    }
}*
```

This is the failure trace

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at demo.Demo1.test(Demo1.java:31)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor$$Lambda$170/0000000000000000.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$139/0000000000000000.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$142/0000000000000000.accept(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
>     at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)   at
>   java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:497)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:487)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:241)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$139/0000000000000000.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$142/0000000000000000.accept(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
>     at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)   at
>   java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:497)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:487)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:241)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$139/0000000000000000.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

Comment: [edit] your question and post the stack trace you are getting with your `NullPointerException`.

Comment: thanks. edited it.

Comment: According to the stack trace you posted, the `NullPointerException` is occurring on line 31 of file `Demo1.java`. Indicate in your question which line that is.

Comment: its this line driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'prm\']/div/a")).click();

Comment: That means that either `driver` is null or that `driver.findElement()` returns null. Can you debug your code? That would tell you if `driver` is null.

Comment: the driver is null. i printed te driver and it prints "drivernull"

Comment: alright, so i added everything in the test method. its now working. that means the issue was with driver.

Answer (score 0):

Please check chromedriver.exe path. It should be in D: drive.

I am not seeing anything incorrect in your code.

Comment: @ShivamSharma ok, please add below version of selenium in your project:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something in your `before()` throws an exception because `driver` is `null`. So `get(url)` or `manage()`.

Most likely it is `get(url)` (you can see that precisely in your stack trace)

So `new ChromeDriver()` probably fails, check your installation.

Hence, when `test` is called, `driver` member variable is still null, so the display is `"null"`.

the [get started](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) example explicits the protocol in the path. This is most likely unrelated but you should change

```
String url="www.google.com";
```

to

```
String url="http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: I downloaded chromedirver again.checked the versions again. its all correct, the chromedriver is compatible with my chrome browser. i also added http to my url. its showing me the same error.

Comment: i also tried running it with firefox, shows me the same error

Comment: According to your stack trace, this is your `test()` method that crashes. If the driver creation failed in before, the exception would occur in `before` method. My conclusion is that your `before` method is never called. Your webdriver is never initialized and then the null pointer exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
String url="www.google.com";
```

to

```
String url="http://www.google.com";
```

Why do we need to do because driver.get method is not adding protocol like "http" or "https" before your url

Comment: I added http, it didnt help.

Comment: Why you are trying to hardcoring this path. Create maven project and in POM.xml add chrome dependency like below:
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>